# Django admin - sorting list_filter

Tags: django, django-admin

[image]

I have 'version' in list_filter, and I want the latest version be after 'All' list item.
In this case, how do I sort the list descending? (All, 3.6.99.108,3.6.99.107...)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258314/how-to-sort-list-filter-labels-for-foreign-key-filters-in-django-admin

Comment: @tuxcanfly true, however this OP holds a better answer

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Define default ordering in model `Meta` class:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # some model fields here
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-version',]
```

If somehow it does not fulfill your purpose you can write your own custom list filter:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter

class VersionFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('version')

    parameter_name = 'version'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        qs = model_admin.queryset(request)
        return [(i, i) for i in qs.values_list('version', flat=True) \
                                  .distinct().order_by('-version')]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(version__exact=self.value())

class MyModel(ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (VersionFilter,)
```

If you get following error `AttributeError: object has no attribute 'queryset'` then you are probably using `Django 1.5+` use `.get_queryset()` instead e.g.

```
qs = model_admin.get_queryset(request)
```

Comment: Or create your own [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) if this isn't desired default ordering behaviour

Comment: @Hedde yup i have added an example for that. I saw your comment after adding the custom filter example. Thanks!

Comment: @Aamir Adnan, model_admin doesn't have `get_queryset` method (`qs = model_admin.get_queryset(request)`). It has `queryset` method. Probably it is needed to change in answer.

Comment: The first solution didn't fulfil my purpose. The second one did, thanks! Also, I've changed 'lookups' to retrieve distinct values, to avoid duplicates:  return [(i, i) for i in qs.values_list('version', flat=True).distinct().order_by('-version')]

Comment: @ron i added `.distinct()` in my answer 10 minutes ago before your comment :)

Comment: @Aamir Adnan, I see it now :). Thanks!

Comment: @Aamir Adnan It's just a small thing, but you don't have to add `by` in the title, because it results in `By by version`