# How to sort django list filter by alphanumeric

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have used default django filter but it not show record by sorting i.e alphanumeric
following is my code

```
class VoteAdminModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('business__poll__town__parent')
```

models

```
class Business(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey('Poll')
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True,null=True)

class Poll(models.Model):
    town = models.ForeignKey('Town', verbose_name="Survey")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class Vote(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
    vote_year = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Year")
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Town(models.Model):
    town_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="Survey")
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', db_column='parent', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Survey")
```

[image]

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560055/django-admin-sorting-list-filter